# Spring Boot Native cache : How to expire/remove cache data by individual keys/elements

Tags: spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

We are calling Identity federation service to acquire user tokens very frequently and almost running load test on Identity service.

A potential solution is to cache the user tokens in existing application, however with native spring-cache, can we expire individual cache entries?

With below example, I was able to clear the cache, removing all entries, however I am trying to expire individual entries.

```java
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames =  {"userTokens"})
public class UserTokenManager {

    static HashMap<String, String> userTokens = new HashMap<>();

    @Cacheable
    public String getUserToken(String userName){
        String userToken = userTokens.get(userName);
        if(userToken == null){
            // call Identity service to acquire tokens
            System.out.println("Adding UserName:" + userName + " Token:" + userToken);
            userTokens.put(userName, userToken);
        }
        return userToken;
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, cacheNames = { "userTokens"})
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3600000)
    public void removeUserTokens() {
        System.out.println("##############CACHE CLEANING##############, " +
            "Next Cleanup scheduled at : " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+ 3600000));
        userTokens.clear();
    }
}
```

Spring Boot application class is as below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can expire a single cache entry by using `@CacheEvict` on a method that takes your cache key. Also, by using Spring's cache and `@Cacheable`, there's no need for the HashMap code (as that's really just a secondary cache).

## Simple Cache

```java
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = {"userTokens"})
public class UserTokenManager {

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserTokenManager.class);

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = {"userTokens"})
    public String getUserToken(String userName) {
        log.info("Fetching user token for: {}", userName);
        String token = ""; //replace with call for token
        return token;
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = {"userTokens"})
    public void evictUserToken(String userName) {
        log.info("Evicting user token for: {}", userName);
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = {"userTokens"}, allEntries = true)
    public void evictAll() {
        log.info("Evicting all user tokens");
    }
}
```

For example:

1. `getUserToken("Joe")   -> no cache, calls API`
2. `getUserToken("Alice") -> no cache, calls API`
3. `getUserToken("Joe")   -> cached`
4. `evictUserToken("Joe") -> evicts cache for user "Joe"`
5. `getUserToken("Joe")   -> no cache, calls API`
6. `getUserToken("Alice") -> cached (as it has not been evicted)`
7. `evictAll()            -> evicts all cache`
8. `getUserToken("Joe")   -> no cache, calls API`
9. `getUserToken("Alice") -> no cache, calls API`

## TTL-based Cache

If you want your tokens to be cached for a certain amount of time, you'll need another `CacheManager` besides the native Spring one. There are a variety of cache options that work with Spring's `@Cacheable`. I'll give an example using Caffeine, a high performance caching library for Java 8. For example, if you know you want to cache a token for 30 minutes, you'll likely want to go with this route.

First, add the following dependencies to your `build.gradle` (or if using Maven, translate the following and put it in your `pom.xml`). Note that you'll want to use the latest versions, or the ones that match with your current Spring Boot version.

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:2.1.4'
compile 'com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.7.0'
```

Once you've added those two dependencies, all you have to do is configure the `caffeine` spec in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.cache.cache-names=userTokens
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=expireAfterWrite=30m
```

Change `expireAfterWrite=30m` to whatever value you'd like tokens to live for. For example, if you wanted 400 seconds, you could change it to `expireAfterWrite=400s`.

Useful links:

- [Caffeine Spec JavaDoc](https://static.javadoc.io/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.7.0/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CaffeineSpec.html)
- [Spring Boot Supported Cache Providers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider)

Comment: Thanks devshawn. Is above caffeine/ expireAfterWrite removes the cache by entry or whole cache ?

Comment: No problem! `expireAfterWrite` will remove the cache by entry. For example, if it's 30 seconds, when a new key gets cached, it will get removed in 30 seconds. The expiration applies to when each individual key is added.

Comment: What about  redisson? Example: redissonClient.getMapCache(Constants.NAME_OF_MAP).put(key, value, 5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); where 5000 is the expiry time by key. What is the difference between using spring redis and redisson? what is better?

Comment: I tried caffeine, the cache value is being overridden by spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=300000 as I am using for some cache this value and for others this one: spring.cache.cache-names=userTokens
spring.cache.caffeine.spec=expireAfterWrite=30m Can you help?

Comment: I ended up removing redis time to live config and replaced it by two custom cache TTL and I defined each cache in Application.java as follows:

Comment: @Bean public CacheManager cacheManager(Ticker ticker) {
   SimpleCacheManager manager = new SimpleCacheManager();
  manager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(buildCache("cacheOne", ticker,config.getCacheOneTimeToLive()), buildCache("cacheTwo", ticker,config.getCacheTwoTimeToLive()));
        return manager;}
    private CaffeineCache buildCache(String name, Ticker ticker, int minutesToExpire) {
        return new CaffeineCache(name, Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(minutesToExpire,TimeUnit.MINUTES).maximumSize(3000).ticker(ticker).build());}

Comment: And dont forget to define ticker as follows: @Bean public Ticker ticker() {return Ticker.systemTicker();}

Comment: Thanks @devshawn, here's a useful guide for Spring Boot with Caffeine Cache: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-with-caffeine-cache/

Answer (score 7):

Spring Cache Abstraction is an abstraction and not an implementation, so it doesn't support setting TTL explicitly at all as this is an implementation-specific feature. For example, if your cache is backed by the `ConcurrentHashMap`, it cannot support TTL out-of-the-box.

In your case, you have 2 options. If what you need is a local cache (i.e. each microservice instance manages their own cache), you can replace Spring Cache Abstraction with [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) which an official dependency provided & managed by Spring Boot. Just need to declare without mentioning the version.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
  <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then you can create an instance of the cache as following. Each token you put into the cache will automatically get removed based on your configuration.

```java
@Service
public class UserTokenManager {
    private static Cache<String, String> tokenCache;   

    @Autowired
    private UserTokenManager (@Value("${token.cache.time-to-live-in-seconds}") int timeToLiveInSeconds) {
        tokenCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                             .expireAfterWrite(timeToLiveInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                             // Optional listener for removal event
                             .removalListener((userName, tokenString, cause) -> System.out.println("TOKEN WAS REMOVED FOR USER: " + userName))
                             .build();
    }

    public String getUserToken(String userName){
        // If cached, return; otherwise create, cache and return
        // Guaranteed to be atomic (i.e. applied at most once per key)
        return tokenCache.get(userName, userName -> this.createToken(userName));
    }

    private String createToken(String userName) {
        // call Identity service to acquire tokens
    }
}
```

Again, this is a **local** cache, which means each microservice will manage their own set of tokens. So if you have 5 instances of the same microservice running, the same user may have 5 tokens lying in all 5 caches depending on which instances handled his requests.

On the other hand, if you need a distributed cache (i.e. multiple microservice instances share the same centralized cache), you need to take a look at [EHCache](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/integrations/spring.html) or [Hazelcast](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-hazelcast.html). In this case, you can continue to use Spring Cache Abstraction and pick one of these library as your implementation by declaring a `CacheManager` from these library (e.g. `HazelcastCacheManager`).

You can then take a look at the respective documentation to further configure your chosen `CacheManager` with TTL for specific caches (e.g. your `tokenCache`). I provided a simple configuration for Hazelcast below as an example.

```java
@Configuration
public class DistributedCacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance(@Value("${token.cache.time-to-live-in-seconds}") int timeToLiveInSeconds) {
        Config config = new Config();                  
        config.setInstanceName("hazelcastInstance");
        
        MapConfig mapConfig = config.getMapConfig("tokenCache");
        mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(timeToLiveInSeconds);
        
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
    }
}
```